# Trouble installing libv8 to use with mini_racer (github page site project using Git bash)

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems, jekyll

1. Hi guys, I'm working on my first website ever using github page site. I've been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6AJ9qPPoyc) on Youtube.I forked a theme from another person to use with my project. After forking and some editing to make it personalized via VS code, I ran `bundle install` (this is the same step @6.40 in the video). My goal for this post is to be able to proceed to `bundle install` and `bundle exec jekyll` on my machine.

My system/version is:

- Windows 11, version 22H2
- gem 3.5.6
- ruby 3.2.3 (2024-01-18 revision 52bb2ac0a6) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
- Jekyll 4.3.3

---

After that I got this error:

```
An error occurred while installing libv8-node (18.16.0.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer was resolved to 0.8.0, which depends on
    libv8-node
```

So I looked up how to fix this. Most people said to use `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8` I tried that and it works and comes back with this below:

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8 
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW... Building native extensions with: '--with-system-v8' This could take a while...
Successfully installed libv8-3.16.14.3 Parsing documentation for libv8-3.16.14.3 Done installing documentation for libv8 after 0 seconds 1 gem installed
```

After that, I ran `bundle install` again. The same error shows regarding mini_racer. Other things I have tried is `gem update --system`, `gem update --system` (shows that latest version installed), and I also tried to specify in VS code `gem 'mini_racer', '0.8.0'` with its version it's looking for in my Gem file. None of these works for me.

Any suggestion? Sorry if this is a dumb question but internet resources I've been stuck trying to look for solutions don't fix the issue at all. Thanks guys

---

My Gemfile looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvayb.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this solution, there are many reasons for this error but this one looks more reliable for your case https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/issues/691#issuecomment-1146779021

Comment: Thanks, I also tried that as well but same thing happened. I just redo this in node.js